# Счетчик для двух функций

Tags: javascript, jquery, счетчики, замыкания

Привет. Помогите пожалуйста проблемку решить.
Две функции. Первая функция догружает по клику на кнопку, вторая сортирует материалы.
Первая функция наращивает счётчик, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при вызове второй функции, счётчик, измененный в первой, сбрасывался в исходное состояние?
Заранее благодарю.

```js
var sortLinks = $('#sort a');
var loadButton = $('#loadMore');
var page = 2;

loadMore.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.get("...", function(data) {

    // догружаем данные
    result.append(data);

    // меняем адрес страницы                                   
    var href = "...";
    history.pushState({}, '', href);

    // наращиваем счётчик
    page++;
  });

  checkPage(page);
  return false;
});

sortLinks.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // сортируем и загружаем данные
  // тут нужно сбросить счётчик на начальную страницу

  checkPage(page);
  return false;
});

function checkPage(page) {
  if (page >= totalPages) {
    loadButton.addClass('is-hidden');
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/K7Om/1

Comment: а исходное это какое? достаточно просто сделать `page=<нужное значение>`

Comment: если исходное значение это 2, то во второй функции нужно просто написать `page = 2`, так как эта переменная общая для обоих функций.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался